Angular 1.5 vs 2.x for ServiceNow Customizations
Does anyone know the technical reason ServiceNow uses Jason version 1.5 instead of the newer releases of Angular? Thanks in advance for information about this.
I've been trying to understand why ServiceNow uses version 1.5 specifically.Thanks

My apologies @testing-ma-lady I meant Angular

AFAIK, the reason ServiceNow is not upgrading to the latest versions of Angular is to maintain backward compatibilities for all existing customers. Older widgets might break on new versions and vice-versa which risks breaking customer portals.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

First, Jason version 1.5 is not a thing. Maybe you mean the old, original version of  Angular?
The technical reason they won't upgrade Angular is that they would have too much technical debt and it would break too many components that they and their customers have developed.
If they did upgrade and all their customers had to re-develop things, it would be a good chance for their customers to migrate to a different platform. Given the amount of work it would take, some customers might decide to try another offering and SN would lose the customers.
ServiceNow wants their customers locked in, so they will continue to support the old Angular even though it is dead.
You can read their official take on Angular support here:
https://support.servicenow.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0965345

ServiceNow customers will continue to be able use, build, and deploy AngularJS experiences without any impact, even after Google
ends Long Term Support (LTS) on December 31, 2021.
At ServiceNow, we will maintain our own version of AngularJS in support of all ServiceNow experiences and products that depend upon
it.

